# Cómo crear un nuevo objeto usando como claves los valores de una propiedad contenida en varios objetos de un array multidimensional

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, objeto, function

Quiero que el objeto `filteredProducts{}` que está vacio me retorne **tech** y **food** como *key* pero me lo devuelve vacio, y no se donde está el fallo.

```javascript
function sortProducts(matrix) {
  //declaro las variables
  const filteredProducts = {};
  let techArray = [];
  let foodArray = [];
  //bucle para recorrer el array input
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    let products = matrix[i];
    //declaro las variables para asignarle los nuevos valores
    let category = products.product;
    let tech = category === "tech";
    //condicional que agrega el valor tech al array 
    if (tech) {
      techArray.push(products[i]);
      filteredProducts.tech = techArray;
    }
  }
  //bucle para recorrer el array input
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    let products = matrix[i];
    //declaro las variables para asignarle los nuevos valores
    let category = products.product;
    let food = category === "food";
    //condicional que agrega el valor tech al array 
    if (food) {
      foodArray.push(products[i]);
      filteredProducts.food = foodArray;

    }
  }
  //retorno los valores en el array vacio
  return filteredProducts;
}

//este es el array de input

let matrix = [
  [{
    product: "MacBook",
    price: 1019,
    category: 'tech'
  },
   {
     product: "Cheerios",
     price: 5,
     category: 'food'
   },
  ],

  [{
    product: "Snickers",
    price: 1.5,
    category: 'food'
  },
   {
     product: "Air Pods",
     price: 129,
     category: 'tech'
   },
  ],

];
sortProducts(matrix);
```

Comment: Intenta evitar las imágenes de código en las preguntas, para nosotros es mas fácil copiar y pegar el código para depurarlo que transcribirlo, puedes pulsar [edit] para ello.

Comment: Hola! lo primero gracias por responderme y explicarmelo tan bien todo lo que hicistes, borre el comentario porque no lo había acabado y se lanzo, estoy empezando a usar este portal y aún no estoy muy familiarizado, como te decia no me deja poner el código me dice que es mucho código y que lo describa, lo hago pero aún así sigue saliendome, voy a intentar lo que me comentas y te reitero las gracias de nuevo por la ayuda!! y por tomarte el tiempo en contestar!

Comment: Pues efectivamente añadiendo caracteres al hacer me ha dejado copiar el código, ya he aprendido algo nuevo jejeje

Comment: Bueno, lo he pulido un poco más indentandolo y agregando el texto del principio que habias eliminado sin querer supongo. Si mi respuesta satisface tu pregunta deberias aceptarlo para que la comunidad lo sepa y la pregunta no quede pendiente para siempre. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás como aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo cuando éstas son correctas para tu caso. Gracias!

Comment: Ya lo hice, gracias por estos pequeños primeros pasos, había realizado alguna pregunta pero nunca me había dicho que había escrito demasiado código! tu respuesta me es totalmente válida y además el código es muchísimo más limpio y sencillo! Graciass!

Comment: De nada.  Me alegro que te sirva :-)  Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejando de lado los fallos que tienes en tu código, el cual no he podido reproducir porque es una imagen, te propongo esta solución a lo que me parece que quieres obtener:

```js
function sortProducts(matrix) {
  const filteredProducts = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      if (filteredProducts[matrix[i][j].category] === undefined) {
        filteredProducts[matrix[i][j].category] = []
      }
      filteredProducts[matrix[i][j].category].push(matrix[i][j])
    }
  }
  return filteredProducts
}

let matrix = [
  [{
      product: "MacBook",
      price: 1019,
      category: 'tech'
    },
    {
      product: "Cheerios",
      price: 5,
      category: 'food'
    },
  ],

  [{
      product: "Snickers",
      price: 1.5,
      category: 'food'
    },
    {
      product: "Air Pods",
      price: 129,
      category: 'tech'
    },
  ],

];
console.log(sortProducts(matrix))
```

## Explicación:

- Dentro del primer `for`, el cual coge cada *array* del objeto **matrix** y devuelve una serie de dos objetos, los recorro de nuevo uno a uno mediante otro `for` para poder llegar a sus propiedades.
- Establezco un condicional para ir montando la salida deseada del objeto **filteredProducts**, el cual debe contener como claves las dos categorias existentes, y para ello accedo a ellas mediante `matrix[i][j].category`, que voy a usar para establecer una nueva clave en **filteredProducts** escribiéndolo con [esta sintaxis de corchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#notaci.c3.b3n_por_corchetes) que me lo permite:

```
filteredProducts[matrix[i][j].category]
```

y como valor de la clave voy a decirle que es un *array* mediante esta asignación:

```
filteredProducts[matrix[i][j].category] = []
```

- De este modo, puedo ir agregando a este nuevo array de la clave los objetos que coincidan en la categoria del objeto en cada ciclo, usando [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) con esta instrucción:

```
filteredProducts[matrix[i][j].category].push(matrix[i][j])
```

y asi vamos a recorrer todos los objetos de todos los *arrays* contenidos en **matrix** y se va a ir creando el nuevo objeto con sus claves y sus *arrays* ordenadamente, el cual, al terminar los ciclos, devolvemos con un **return**.

- Cabe decir que este condicional:

```
if (filteredProducts[matrix[i][j].category] === undefined) {
  filteredProducts[matrix[i][j].category] = []
}
```

es necesario para indicarle a javascript que esa clave es un *array* la primera vez que intente acceder a ella, pues si aún no existe la clave será **undefined**. El resto de ciclos, si ya existe, no la volverá a sobreescribir sino que se saltará esa asignación.

Ya nos dirás si es lo que pretendias realizar y te sirve o no.